# How to detect onclick on a model in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, model, onclick

I was wandering if there is any method in three.js that allows the user to click on a model (for example an imported gltf file from blender) and as a result of the click something else to happen (for example a pop up box or an image is displayed).

I was trying to look it up in the three.js website but all found was the raycaster class. But from my understanding this will only work with objects that have a mesh and thus only the ones that are made in three.js itself with the geometry properties.

I also found tutorials with the use of threex.domevents. But once again I don't see how this can be used with the models imported from blender. I tried using it but it only caused my models to disappear from the screen.

So is there another solution? or is it impossible?

I really appreciate the help,thank you very much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset=UTF-8 />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/mycss.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <script src="three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="GLTFLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="threex.domevents.js"></script>
            <script>
                let scene, camera, renderer;

                        function init() {
                            scene = new THREE.Scene();
                            scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);
                            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,1,5000);
                            //camera.rotation.y = 45/180*Math.PI;
                            camera.position.x = 0;
                           //camera.position.y = 100;
                            camera.position.z = 2000;

                            const domEvents = new THREEx.DomEvents(camera, renderer.domElement);

                            domEvents.addEventListener(car, 'click', event => {   
                              scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x000000);
                            });

                            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
                            controls.addEventListener('change', renderer);


                            hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight (0x404040,100);
                            scene.add(hlight);


                            directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff,100);
                            directionalLight.position.set(0,1,0);
                            directionalLight.castShadow = true;
                            scene.add(directionalLight);

                            light = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
                            light.position.set(0,300,500);
                            scene.add(light);

                            light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
                            light2.position.set(500,100,0);
                            scene.add(light2);

                            light3 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
                            light3.position.set(0,100,-500);
                            scene.add(light3);

                            light4 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
                            light4.position.set(-500,300,500);
                            scene.add(light4);


                            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
                            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
                            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


                            var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

                            loader.load('car.gltf', function(gltf){
                            car = gltf.scene.children[0];
                            car.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);
                            scene.add(gltf.scene);
                            car.position.z -=370;
                            car.position.x = 500;
                            animate();
                            });



                            var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

                            loader.load('scene.gltf', function(gltf){
                            car1 = gltf.scene.children[0];
                            car1.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);
                            car1.position.x = -500;
                            scene.add(gltf.scene);
                            animate();
                            });
                        }

                        function animate() {
                            renderer.render(scene,camera);
                            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                        }

                    init();
            </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Car model can be found at :
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/1972-datsun-240k-gt-non-commercial-use-only-b2303a552b444e5b8637fdf5169b41cb

I only want to learn how to do it so all my code is based on tutorials from YouTube.

Comment: It's better to provide the code of the approach you tried, including the model itself. Or you can ask this question at the [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/). All the models you load into the scene become objects with buffer geometries and materials in format of Three.js.

Comment: @prisoner849 Thank you I'll probably will do that.

Comment: The raycaster works just fine with loaded objects. Places it doesn't work include skinned objects and morphtarget objects but you can use GPU picking for that case. See [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-picking.html).

Comment: @KamilaJarek: I am looking into exact same problem, did you get any solution/lead?

Comment: @kshirish No unfortunately I just had to work around it. I just used an object I build in threejs and then triggered whatever I wanted to happen with that

Answer (score 0):

The solution is only Raycaster (as 3D world is different from 2D world)
Following is the example code for reference -

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects ); 

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

        intersects[0].object.callback();

    }

}
```

Here i have kept a callback in 3D object which will get executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using raycaster. You can traverse the gltf model into a mesh like this

```
loader.load("nameOfObject.gltf", function (gltf) {
    gltf.scene.traverse(function (child) {
        if (child.isMesh) {
            let m = child;
            m.receiveShadow = true;
            m.castShadow = true;
            m.material.flatShading = true;
            sceneMeshes.push(m);
        }
        if (child.isLight) {
            let l = child;
            l.castShadow = true;
            l.shadow.bias = -0.003;
            l.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
            l.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
        }
    });
    scene.add(gltf.scene);

    sceneMeshes.push(gltf.scene);
}, (xhr) => {
    console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

then use the raycaster on it

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
    const mouse = {
        x: (event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1,
        y: -(event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 + 1,
    };
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(sceneMeshes, false);

    const color = Math.random() * 0xffffff;

    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        let n = new THREE.Vector3();
        n.copy(intersects[0].face.normal);
        n.transformDirection(intersects[0].object.matrixWorld);
        const selectedObject = intersects[0];
        alert('this is a Drink');
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't worked for me(

Comment: Maybe because my model is animated

Answer (score 0):

I spent around 2 hours trying to solve it without success.

In the end, I solved it stupidly. I just created a cube with 100% transparency over my model... then applied a standard raycast solution for that cube, and it worked.